# PL/SQL checking if number is Integer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to check my employee table if there is any employee who works as an
employee for exactly one year or two years, or three years, ...
The Problem for me now is that i dont know how i can check if a number is
an integer or not.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE jubilar
IS
  v_cur_date DATE := TO_DATE('03-JAN-2012');
  v_cur_year NUMBER;
  v_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  v_last_name employees.last_name%TYPE;
  v_hire_date employees.hire_date%TYPE;
  CURSOR c_emp_cursor IS
    SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_emp_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO v_first_name, v_last_name, v_hire_date;
    EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    v_cur_year := round((v_cur_date - v_hire_date) / 365, 1);
    IF v_cur_year ???
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_first_name || ' ' || v_last_name || ' ist heute ' || v_cur_year || ' Jahre im Unternehmen tätig.');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_emp_cursor;
END jubilar;
/
```

At this line

```
IF v_cur_year ??
```

I need to check if v_cur_year is an integer or not. Because if it is the employee
works for exactly X year as an employee. And i need to know that.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE jubilar
IS
  v_cur_date DATE := TO_DATE('03/01/12', 'dd/mm/yy');
  v_cur_year NUMBER;
  v_cur_year_temp VARCHAR2(100);
  v_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  v_last_name employees.last_name%TYPE;
  v_hire_date employees.hire_date%TYPE;
  CURSOR c_emp_cursor IS SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_emp_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO v_first_name, v_last_name, v_hire_date;
    EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    v_cur_year := round((v_cur_date - v_hire_date) / 365, 1);
    v_cur_year_temp := TO_CHAR(v_cur_year);

    IF REGEXP_COUNT(v_cur_year_temp, ',') = 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_first_name || ' ' || v_last_name || ' ist heute ' || v_cur_year || ' Jahre im Unternehmen tätig.' || TO_CHAR(v_hire_date));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_emp_cursor;
END jubilar;
/
```

But it gives me wrong persons with hire_date for example 17/01/2005

I also tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE jubilar
IS
  v_cur_date DATE := TO_DATE('03/01/12', 'dd/mm/yy');
  v_cur_year NUMBER;
  v_first_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  v_last_name employees.last_name%TYPE;
  v_hire_date employees.hire_date%TYPE;
  CURSOR c_emp_cursor IS SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_emp_cursor;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp_cursor INTO v_first_name, v_last_name, v_hire_date;
    EXIT WHEN c_emp_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    v_cur_year := round((v_cur_date - v_hire_date) / 365, 1);

    IF trunc(v_cur_year) = v_cur_year THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_first_name || ' ' || v_last_name || ' ist heute ' || v_cur_year || ' Jahre im Unternehmen tätig.' || TO_CHAR(v_hire_date));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_emp_cursor;
END jubilar;
/
```

But it gives me wrong persons with hire_date for example 17/01/2005

Comment: You can use `if trunc(v_cur_year) = v_cur_year` to check if the number is integer or not. But how will you handle leap years?

Comment: This is not a solution :(. The actual date is 03-JAN-2012. With IF trunc(v_cur_year) = v_cur_year i get 13-JAN-2001 für 11 years, 24-DEC-2005 for 6 years, 14-Jan-2007 for 5 years, .... The only correct person i get is 03.01.06 for 6 years.

Comment: You may want to give some thought to the proper handling of a hire date of 29-FEB-2012. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for employees who are employed exactly two years at e.g. January 14th, you can use this:

```
select *
from employees
where months_between(DATE '2014-01-14', trunc(hire_date)) / 12 = 2;
```

<sup>(I prefer using ANSI date literals over the `to_date()` function. Works on multiple DBMS and is less typing)</sup>

`months_between(...) / 12` will result in a fractional value if it's not exactly one year and therefore the comparison with a non-fractional value will fail.

Just change the comparison date (`DATE '2014-01-14'`) and the condition ( `=2`) to accommodate for other dates or durations.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27c3d/4

Comment: It works but i think you mean months_between(DATE '2014-01-14', hire_date) / 12 = 2;

Answer (score 1):

This may help you ..

```
   DECLARE
   d1    DATE := TO_DATE ('01/12/12', 'mm/dd/yy');
   d2    DATE := SYSDATE;
   n1    NUMBER;
   chk   VARCHAR2 (100);
    BEGIN
   n1 := ROUND ( (d2 - d1) / 365, 1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n1);
   chk := TO_CHAR (n1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (chk);

   IF REGEXP_COUNT (chk, '.') != 0
    THEN
      ---YOUR LOGIC
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: No it does'nt. IF REGEXP_COUNT(chk, '.') != 0 is true for 01/12/12 and for 02/12/12. So its not correct.

Comment: So what will be your incoming date format?? and here you will look for integer or not.. the best way is to convert to character and check as we do in other programming languages..

Comment: Since the date is dynamic you must use to_date and you should check for '.' not for ','

Comment: That cannot be cause there is no '.' in the date, there is just a ',' in it. however.. problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
with y as 
   (select trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12 * LEVEL)) as the_date, LEVEL as anniversary
   from dual
   connect by LEVEL <= 6)
select first_name, last_name, hire_date, anniversary, the_date
   join y on  the_date = hire_date
```